# Lines of same bray-curtis similarity plotted onto MDS in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

Does anybody know how to plot lines of equal similarity (as determined by Bray-Curtis matrix) onto an MDS plot in R.

I have managed to overlay a cluster (`hclust()`) onto an MDS (`metaMDS()`) for the community composition data but want to draw compositional hulls around sites of the same or higher similarity.

Comment: Not really, there isn't an easy (or otherwise?) way to map a real-valued dissimilarity onto a rank-dissimilarity-preserving NMDS space. I have in the past, fiddled with the idea of *predicting* dissimilarity from a selected sample using `ordisurf` to model the pre-computed dissimilarity as a function of `x` and `y` coordinates in the NMDS solution, but I never followed it up. If you just want to select groups of sites delineated from the hierarchical cluster analysis at a specified dissimilarity @EDi's Answer is the **vegan** way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a hclust-object you can use `cutree()` to extract groups with as dissimilarity greater than a specific value.

This grouping variable can be plotted onto the NMDS-plot via `ordihull()` or `ordispider()`.

Here is an example:

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)

# nmds
nmds <- metaMDS(dune)

# cluster
clus <- hclust(vegdist(dune))
plot(clus)
rect.hclust(clus, h = 0.6)
```

[image]

```
# extract groups with similarity > 0.6 between
group_clus <- cutree(clus, h=0.6)


# plot those 4 groups
plot(nmds, display = 'sites', type = 'text')
ordihull(nmds, groups=group_clus)
```

[image]

Comment: should be 'vegdist()' instead of 'dvegdist()'.